# No Login pop up appears when domain "A" includes image from domain "B". Image is in folder which is protected by basic http auth

Tags: php, security, authentication, authorization

Domain "A" includes an image from Domain "B"

`<img src="https://DOMAIN_B/basic-auth/protected_image/secure.jpg">`

Domain "B" has basic HTTP auth.

```
<?php
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm='Please login'");
    exit;
?>
```

My question is why there is no login pop up appears on Domain "A". Chrome gives error "401 unauthorized.". 
But technically the browser should pop up the login display on Domain "A". On the other hand, everything is working fine locally and https://jsfiddle.net/w493nnp9/18/.

You can visit this link and the page shows login pop up. But why other domains do not show.
https://jsfiddle.net/w493nnp9/18/

Thank you

Comment: Replace your link by prefix "user:passwd@", 

Example: "user:passwd@httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd"

Answer (score 0):

If it displayed the login form, that would be a potential CSRF attack on site B.

Let's suppose users reuse their passwords, that's not a strong assumption, many people do that. If site A includes an image from basic auth site B, the user will think that site A is requesting their password. If it's the same as on site B, they will get logged in to site B without any intention to do so. From then on, as basic auth info is persisted until the browser is closed, site A could perform regular CSRF against site B (unless there is protection of course, which there should be, because the user could have logged on to B deliberately as well).

Even with further CSRF protection on site B, if the login popup was displayed in your scenario, it would make http basic auth inherently vulnerable to login csrf.

Answer (score 0):

Login popup does not shows in `<img>` tag, POP-up will show in `<iframe>` example : `<iframe src="https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd">`

Why other domain not work ? 
It is because other domain has a "Cross-ORIGIN" policy, (look in response header).

For example : your provided link "https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd" , there is **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** Here * means this domain allowing everyone to fetch data.  Check your domain "B" header-response for, if it has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" or not.

Basically domain "B" need to have header =  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*", to work.

thanks,
jaikey